# how to send API request based on users input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to java script and node JS. I am trying to create a simple app where the user can convert currency values by entering the amount and the currency type. i checked this API request its working fine, but i have no idea how to use  html input tag to get the inputs and send it to the API request form.

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://currency-exchange.p.rapidapi.com/exchange");

req.query({
    "q": "1",
    "from": "USD",
    "to": "LKR"
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "currency-exchange.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "1599d15183msh1ede0c59134d7c4p1c921bjsnedcdcb4dded9"
});

req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is not a web browser. It doesn't have input tags.

If you want to communicate between a browser and Node.js then you'll need to create some kind of connection between them.

Typically this would involve writing a web service using Node.js (e.g. with [the Express module](https://expressjs.com/)) and then communicating to it with [a form submission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) or with [an Ajax request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Alternatively, you could bundle Node.js and the browser together into a single app. [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) is a populate framework for doing that.